# Change VMware fusion NAT setting

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have a virtual machine that I like to use in NAT mode, but by default, VMWare fusion internal DHCP server issues IP addresses in the 192.168.1.0 space.  This means that when I am traveling and using other networks that might use this same space, I can't connect to the VM.

How can I change VMWare's internal DHCP server to issue IPs from a less common IP space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this really easy in VMWare Workstation, but on Fusion, not so much. Please refer to the following VMWare Knowledge Base [article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026510). You'll need to edit a file, and restart your VMWare services.